# Pandas Series From If-Then-Else Statement

Tags: python, pandas

What is the most idiomatic way to generate a Pandas series using an if-then-else statement (or similar)?

I have a messy set of data that is structured like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "label": ["a","b","a","b","a","b"],
    "name": ["normal","normal","normal","special","normal","special"],
    "value": [1,2,3,4,5,6]
})
```

I'm trying to create a new label by looking up values from `label` in a dictionary, but want to return a special new label if the `name` value is "special".

I was able to get things working with df.apply:

```
mapping = {"a": "apple", "b": "banana"}

df["new_label"] = df.apply(
    lambda x:"pear" if x['name'] == "special" else mapping[x['label']],
    axis=1
)
```

However `apply` already slows down my program when running on ~60k rows of data and I'm anticipating much more. Is there a more idiomatic and vectorized way to do this type of operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df["new_label"] = np.where(df['name'] == "special", 'pear', df['label'].map(mapping))

print (df)
  label     name  value new_label
0     a   normal      1     apple
1     b   normal      2    banana
2     a   normal      3     apple
3     b  special      4      pear
4     a   normal      5     apple
5     b  special      6      pear
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for and it's much faster than df.apply. Thanks!